# How to get a value from a list of Dictionary column

Tags: json, list, dataframe, key

I have a column with list. Within list some are empty list and some of them are list of dictionary. I need to get a value from a key if type is vendor. I tried different ways but was not successful. For example

```
ColumnName
[]
[{'ID': 'D6130732', 'type': 'Driver'}, {'ID': 'V169R454', 'type': 'Vendor'}]
[{'ID': 'V1139I98', 'type': 'Vendor'}]
[{'ID': 'D13090632', 'type': 'Driver'}]
[{'ID': 'V682541632', 'type': 'Vendor'}, {'ID': 'D1852432', 'type': 'Driver'}]
[]
[]
```

I was able to access the first element with list[0]['ID'] index like but not for every column in a dataframe. I want it something like below

```
columnName
V169R454
V1139I98
V682541632
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# apply literal_eval on ColumnName (if necessary):
from ast import literal_eval
df["ColumnName"] = df["ColumnName"].apply(literal_eval)

df["ColumnName"] = df["ColumnName"].apply(
    lambda lst: [val["ID"] for val in lst if val["type"] == "Vendor"]
)
df = df.explode("ColumnName").dropna()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ColumnName
1    V169R454
2    V1139I98
4  V682541632
```